# A condition equivalent to equicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am doing a problem which is an application of the Arzela-Ascoli theorem, which boils down to proving that a certain condition is equivalent to equicontinuity.

Specifically, I am given a sequence of real valued absolutely continuous functions $\{f_n\}$ on the interval $[0, 1]$ and told that there is a constant $K$ such that $\int_0^1 (f'_n(x))^2 dx \leq K$ for all $n$,

The absolute continuity of the functions lets me conclude that $f_n' \in L^1([0, 1])$ for all $n$, but I don't know how to prove equicontinuity from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: use Cauchy-Schwarz to bound $|f(b)-f(a)| = \left|\int\limits_{a}^{b}{f'(x)\text{ d}x}\right|$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this helps, but I am thinking Cauchy Schwartz inequality is helpful here, $|f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(y)|=|\int\limits_{y}^{x}f_{n}'(t)dt|\leq(\int\limits_{y}^{x}f_{n}'(t)^{2}dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}(\int\limits_{y}^{x}1dt)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \sqrt{K}|x-y|^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Let $\epsilon>0$, $\delta=\frac{\epsilon^{2}}{K}$.